# Replace Any Occurrence of "P" in String With A Value From Another Table

Tags: sql

I have a column, **sort_order** in a table that contains a string of numbers, a delimiter and some **P** values:

**1150||P||1168||1144||1149||1147||1164||1152||P||1148||1162||1163||P||1156||1157||1154||**

I would like to replace any **P** values in this string with another value from the **event_tile_id** column of *another* table.

So far I've drafted this SQL below with no luck.  What changes can I make to this Query to get the effect I need?

```
`SELECT sort_order, 
(
    REPLACE(sort_order,'P', 
        (SELECT TOP 1 event_tile_id 
        FROM daily_email_sales_today) 
    )
)
as sort_order    
FROM daily_email_preview`
```

Removed "default_SaleID" from Query.  Replace should now have 4 arguments.

Comment: Which RMDBS? and if SQL Server, which version?

Comment: Yeah, I'm confused as to how a replace function can take four arguments.

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"?  Is it a syntax error, a general failure, nose demons?

Comment: Just updated the Replace function to have 4 arguments @DaaaahWhoosh

Comment: @christiandev -- Not quite sure.  I'm using this query within ExactTarget's Query tool which I know has some SQL limitations.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

Since you don't have any joins, why not do a simpler update query using a static value?

```
DECLARE @update VARCHAR(100)
SET @update = (SELECT TOP 1 event_tile_id FROM daily_email_sales_today)

update daily_email_preview

SET sort_order = replace(sort_order,'P', @update)
```

Or even,

```
update daily_email_preview

SET sort_order = replace(sort_order,'P', '<new value>')
```

Assuming you are using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Along the same thought process as @Eric_Hauenstein if you are running this in a TSQL process:

```
declare @rSTR as varchar(50)

SELECT TOP 1 @rSTR = event_tile_id FROM daily_email_sales_toda

SELECT sort_order, REPLACE(sort_order,'P', @rSTR) as sort_order    
FROM daily_email_preview
```

Comment: just depends on what you need the output to be formatted as, a list, a replace to etc... both will work.  The bigger question then becomes how you intend to use this substitution code.